# Is transfer of long term investment proceeds from India considered taxable in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, investing, interest

I am Indian origin and I have done many investment in India thru NRE bank account.(legally send money to India.) I have done all investment after I pay taxes in USA.

All investment are long term, so according to Indian tax rule its tax free investment.

But I want to bring all those money back to USA either to buy property, pay for my child's education, etc.

Question are:
Do I need to pay taxes on all amount I bring from India? 
Do I need to pay taxes only on interest I earned from India? (15% long term insurance)

Answer (score 1):

If you are a US resident (not necessarily citizen) then yes, you do have to pay capital gains taxes on any capital gains, including interest from assets oversees (like interest from a savings account). Additionally you have to report all your foreign bank accounts according to FATCA (https://www.irs.gov/businesses/corporations/foreign-account-tax-compliance-act-fatca).